# GIT clone error - remote repository corruption

Tags: ruby, git, github

While cloning a git repo, got error as below

```
remote: Counting objects: 32924, done.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git config --global pack.window "0"
```

May this work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```

This may help you